# postgres pg_restore append data

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a pg backup created using `pg_dump` custom format. I'm trying to restore into a DB which already has some data, using `pg_restore` data-only. This fails in scenarios where same data (some rows) is present in DB as well as dump. 
Is there a way to ignore such rows and proceed with restoring the rest of data ?

Comment: Why not to restore the dump just to the new database?

Comment: I don't want to lose the present data in DB. I need to append the backup onto current content in DB.